# Spring Scoped Proxy working for fields of the Scoped Proxy Beans fields but not the beans itself?

Tags: java, spring, proxy

This is the code I have:

SpringConfiguration:

```
package biz.tugay;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 25/12/15 Time: 19:30 */

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.tugay")
public class SpringConfiguration {
}
```

Foo:

```
package biz.tugay;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 25/12/15 Time: 19:36 */

public interface Foo {
    String getState();
}
```

FooImpl:

```
package biz.tugay;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 25/12/15 Time: 19:31 */

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.UUID;

@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    private final String state = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Bar:

```
package biz.tugay;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 25/12/15 Time: 19:35 */

public interface Bar {
    Foo getFoo();
}
```

BarImpl:

```
package biz.tugay;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 25/12/15 Time: 19:33 */

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class BarImpl implements Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

and the Test Class:

```
package biz.tugay;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class TestClass {

    final static Class<SpringConfiguration> SPRING_CONFIGURATION_CLASS = SpringConfiguration.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SPRING_CONFIGURATION_CLASS);

        final Bar barOne = applicationContext.getBean(BarImpl.class);
        final Bar barTwo = applicationContext.getBean(BarImpl.class);

        out.println("barOne == barTwo: " + (barOne == barTwo));
        out.println("barOne.getFoo == barTwo.getFoo: " + (barOne.getFoo() == barTwo.getFoo()));

        out.println(barOne.getFoo().getState());
        out.println(barTwo.getFoo().getState());

    }
}
```

And the output will be:

```
barOne == barTwo: true
barOne.getFoo == barTwo.getFoo: true
064bdb74-cad7-4d13-86fe-a4fc0021e5a0
c6f2d9be-09b4-456d-9414-8ece2f2acc9e
```

My question is,

I understand that 064bdb74-cad7-4d13-86fe-a4fc0021e5a0 is not equal to c6f2d9be-09b4-456d-9414-8ece2f2acc9e because FooImpl is actually ScopedProxy.

What I do not understand is, how come barOne.getFoo can be equal to barTwo.getFoo?

How is this possible:

```
barOne.getFoo() == barTwo.getFoo()
barOne.getFoo().getState() != barTwo().getFoo().getState()
```

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unterstand the output at first you need to understand how and what is doing the Spring Framework. Lets start with the idea that when you are injecting "short lived" scope bean into a "long lived" scope bean (in your case the prototype bean into singleton bean) Spring injects an AOP proxy in place of the scoped bean.

> That is, you need to inject a proxy object that exposes the same public interface as the scoped object but that can also retrieve the real target object from the relevant scope (such as an HTTP request) and delegate method calls onto the real object.

Basically there are two main types of proxies the JDK proxy and CGLIB proxies (default).

So lets go back to the example code and try to understand what is going on ...
When your application starts Spring Framework creates two beans the `Foo` and the `Bar` but both beans are not just a simple implementations (FooImpl and BarImpl) but are proxies (the CglibAopProxy's).
So in your `TestClass` class you have 2 references to the same AopProxy of `BarImpl` the barOne and barTwo. As the `Bar` is scoped as singleton the underling target class of the AopProxy is the same object (BarImpl) which is pre-inililized. And this `Bar` AopProxy has a injected AopPorxy of type  `Foo`, so when you are executing following code `barOne.getFoo() == barTwo.getFoo()` it evaluates to true, as both `barOne` and `barTwo` have the same instance of AopProxy (not the target class), but when you are calling the `barTwo().getFoo().getState()` the AopProxy is creating a new instance of target class (FooImpl) and exeutes the `getState()` method on it. So each call to the `bar.getFoo().getState()` will create a new instance of `FooImpl` and then execute its `getState()` method.

Comment: It is strange how it know when it needs to replace the proxy with the new instance!

Comment: Basically it does not change the proxy with the new instance, if just executes the public method on the target class. That is the idea of proxy. And if you wonder what is the target, proxy just gets the target from IOC which just returns new instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight of code:

- The code is using prototype scoped bean inside Singleton.
- Then the bean proxy mode ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS is used.

The result is expected. why?

- As UUID is final class see
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html. So trying to get a proxy is not possible and you will get a new object each time.

Comment: You should see @Babl 's answer above.